# don't return the output after executing command via shell

Tags: php, linux, shell, fedora

After execution of php script in *Fedora 20*:

```
echo shell_exec('which systemctl');
```

empty string is displayed.

If to execute '*which systemctl*' in command line, the following is showed:

```
/usr/bin/which: no systemctl in (/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)
```

How to me to receive this output by means of php?

Comment: use `exec()` with the optional output parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `systemctl` is not on your path (or not on you system) `which systemctl` returns the error message

```
/usr/bin/which: no systemctl in (/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)
```

When you run it in PHP using `shell_exec('which systemctl');` the standard error is not collected, and the standard out is empty. Hence PHP sees an empty string.

You can get standard error using this command:

```
shell_exec('which systemctl 2>&1');
```

Comment: That's not correct in full sense. Example: I have only `echo shell_exec('which systemctl');` in my PHP file, but I'm getting the message about absent binary properly (so no STDERR to STDOUT redirect, but `shell_exec()` still collects output)

Comment: @AlmaDo : the return value of `shell_exec()` is the stdout of the executed command, and stderr goes to PHP's stderr. Try running `$result = shell_exec('which blah')` - you will still see the error message, and `$result` will be NULL. If you redirect stderr for the command onto its stdout (that's what `2>&1` is doing) then `$result` will contain both the stdout and stderr of the executed command.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using passthru in my project like the code below:

```
$output = '';
ob_start();
passthru('which systemctl', $output);
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

And shell_exec also return an output please see the doc here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

But either one passthru and shell_exec is working.